# Route in Yii2 doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2

I cant to make request to my controller in Yii2

I have controller /controllers/IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionCreateAccount()
    {
        return Json::encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
    }
}
```

In my config/web.php

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false
    ],
```

When I try to make request **http://account.ll/Index/CreateAccount**
I receive an error

```
Unable to resolve the request "Index/CreateAccount".
```

When I try to make request **http://account.ll/Index** I got the same error

**Whats wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

1. http://account.li/index/index or just http://account.li/index (because index is the default action). If the default controller is IndexController, you can access it like that - http://account.li/.
2. http://account.li/index/create-account

Controller and action names in actual url should be in lowercase. Action names containing more than one word are transformed with hyphens in between words.

Comment: 1) Yes, in my case Index is default controller

Comment: 2) I trying, but its not help.

Comment: It's kind of tautology. I recommend to call it SiteController (it also called like this by default).

Comment: Maybe there is typo in folder name "controllert". Should be "controllers". Provide more information. Relying on the written information it should work.

Comment: It is my mistake in stackoverflow, changed to controllers.

Comment: Changed to SiteController from IndexController, but when I try to make request to http://accounts.ll/site/createaccount I receive 404 code error

Comment: It should be "create-account", but this is not the reason in this case. Are you sure you applying urlManager configuration correctly? Maybe you put it outside of the 'components' array?

Comment: >> Controller and action names in actual url should be in lowercase
Yes, it was problem - thanks

Comment: In Yii 1.1.14 I can youse CamelCase, now I cant =(

Comment: This is actually topic for another question. The current problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
public function actionCreateAccount()
```

to

```
public function actionCreateaccount()
```

Comment: Just need to change in url from http://account.ll/Index/CreateAccount to http://account.ll/Index/create-account

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change in url from http://account.ll/Index/CreateAccount to http://account.ll/Index/create-account